# get <audio> </audio> to play an mp3 file in an HTTPresponse in django

Tags: django, mp3

I'm making a django app that basically saves any mp3 file you upload and creates a model for it. Then, when you select a song from a list, you call a view that generates the HTML required play the selected mp3 file:

```
def playAudioFile(request, title):
    fname= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upandplay/songdir/' + title + '.mp3')
    f = open(fname,"rb") 
    response = HttpResponse(f.read())
    response['Content-Type'] ='audio/mp3'
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(fname )
    return render(request, 'playlist.html', {'response': response})
```

My html template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class='row'>

        {{response}}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I get redirected to the right url but the song doesn't play. How can I get the song to play?

Thanks so much beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote works only for forms and django variables and stuff not files from server.You need to send it a POST request and then receive response.
 Instead you could try something like this.

In your template add a html audio tag

```
<audio id='myaudio'  preload= 'auto' controls  type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

A button which calls the javascript function

```
<button type="button" id='playfile' value = 'Play' onclick=play()>Play</button>
```

And the javascript

```
function play()
{
         var source = document.getElementById('myaudio');
         source.src = 'your file location on the server'+ your_file_name;        
}
```

Make sure the location is within server files in your app folder.Javascript does not load files from our local machine.For example of your mp3 files are in myapp/static folder ,your file location will be '/static/'.